# Сортировка RadioGroup

Tags: delphi

В Delphi есть таблица, поля заполняются из БД. Необходимо выполнить сортировку по возрастанию и убыванию в определенных столбцах. Для этого созданы `RadioGroup1` и `RadioGroup2`. Сначала выбирается столбец для сортировки в `RadioGroup1`, затем порядок сортировки в `RadioGroup2`.
Проблема в том, что если имена столбцов в БД на русском, то при клике на `Item` в `RadioGroup` выскакивает ошибка, если же они на латинице, то код работает, но тогда возникает другая проблема: мне надо, чтобы в `RadioGroup1` названия столбцов, по которым происходит сортировка, были на русском (сейчас они имеют такое же название, как названия столбцов, на латинице) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]Если caption столбцов в таблице я могу задать, то с `caption` у итемов `RadioGroup1` так сделать не получится.
Какой код применить, чтобы сортировались таблицы с русскими названиями полей, или как задать `caption` у `RadioGroup1` `Items`?

```
procedure TForm1.RadioGroup1Click(Sender: TObject);
var ns: string;
 begin
  case RadioGroup2.ItemIndex of
  0: ns:=' ASC';
  1: ns:=' DESC';
end;

with RadioGroup1 do
DM.TableSalon.Sort:=Items[ItemIndex]+ns;
end;

end.
```

Comment: казалось бы, столько вариантов решения вокруг. Ну зачем именно caption передавать в сортировку? почему в asc/desc вы смогли определить нужный вариант по индексу, а для определения столбца нет?

Answer (score 1):

Вот вы решаете задачу: у вас 2 радио-группы. В одной столбцы, в другой порядок сортировки. В таблицу вы в итоге передаете наименование столбца и порядок сортировки. Во втором случае по индексу элемента вы можете определить как надо сортировать набор. Почему же в аналогичной ситуации вы не можете также поступить со столбцами?

1. Поименуйте ваши группы нормальным образом, чтобы они отражали смысл `SortFieldRadioGroup` и `SortOrderRadioGroup`, или варианты любые другие варианты (`FieldRadioGroup`, `sfRadioGroup`, `SortFieldRG` и т.п., но не `radionGroup1`).
2. Назначьте обоим группам один и тот же обработчик `Click`, назовите его тоже общим названием - `SortChange`
3. Заполните `items` нужными значениями для обоих групп. Установите `itemIndex`по умолчанию
4. Реализуйте метод `SortChange`

Заведите константные массивы для соответствия полей и порядка сортировки в соответствии с тем, как они расположены в группах и просто используйте их

```
procedure TMainForm.SortChange(Sender: TObject);
const
    fields : array[0..1] of string = ('fio', 'date');
    order  : array[0..1] of string = (' asc', ' desc');   
begin
    DM.TableSalon.Sort := fields[SortFieldRG.itemIndex] + order[SortOrderRG.itemIndex];
end;
```